# ArangoDB foxx-manager with gulp doesn't know command --server.database

Tags: node.js, cmd, gulp, arangodb

I want to run setup.js script every time i change it. I wrote following gulp script:

```
gulp.task('db_server_setup', function(){
    gulp.src(paths.db_server_setup)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.db_dist))
        .pipe(callback(() => {
            process.execFile('C:/Program Files/ArangoDB 2.8/bin/foxx-manager.exe', ['--server.database "my_db_name" run "/db" setup'], {stdio: 'inherit'}, exec_output);
        }));
});
```

But it results in:

> { [Error: Command failed: C:/Program Files/ArangoDB
>   2.8/bin/foxx-manager.exe --server.database "my_db_name" run "/db" setup
>       C:/Program Files/ArangoDB 2.8/bin/foxx-manager.exe: unrecognized option '--server.database "my_db_name" run "/db" setup'
>       Did you mean one of these? --help  --quiet
>       2016-02-16T13:42:17Z [1564] FATAL illegal option
>       ]
>         killed: false,
>         code: 1,
>         signal: null,
>         cmd: 'C:/Program Files/ArangoDB 2.8/bin/foxx-manager.exe --server.database "my_db_name" run "/db" setup' }
>       C:/Program Files/ArangoDB 2.8/bin/foxx-manager.exe: unrecognized option '--server.database "my_db_name" run "/db" setup'
>
> Did you mean one of these? --help  --quiet
>
> 2016-02-16T13:42:17Z [1564] FATAL illegal option

When I exec `"C:/Program Files/ArangoDB 2.8/bin/foxx-manager.exe" --server.database "organize_me" run "/db" setup` it runs succesfully

> {"code": 200}

How can i achieve to rerun setup script with gulp everytime I change it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a Node problem than an ArangoDB problem.

`child_process.execFile` takes the name of an executable as well as an arguments array. Your arguments array currently looks like this:

```
['--server.database "my_db_name" run "/db" setup']
```

As far as I can tell that is the equivalent of passing the following argument on the command line:

```
"--server.database \"my_db_name\" run \"/db\" setup"
```

So what you actually want is probably this:

```
['--server.database', 'my_db_name', 'run', '/db', 'setup']
```